# Mutate column values instead of column names

Tags: r, dplyr

```
library(tidyverse)

# Attempt 1
tribble(
  ~A, ~Y, ~V1, ~V2, ~V3,
  "One", 2, 89, 52, 37,
  "Two", 3, 45, 34, 86,
  "alpha", 1, 33, 36, 43,
  "beta", 1, 21, 33, 45,

) %>% 
  mutate(selectYCol = paste0("V", Y))

#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#>   A         Y    V1    V2    V3 selectYCol
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>     
#> 1 One       2    89    52    37 V2        
#> 2 Two       3    45    34    86 V3        
#> 3 alpha     1    33    36    43 V1        
#> 4 beta      1    21    33    45 V1

# Attempt 2
tribble(
  ~A, ~Y, ~V1, ~V2, ~V3,
  "One", 2, 89, 52, 37,
  "Two", 3, 45, 34, 86,
  "alpha", 1, 33, 36, 43,
  "beta", 1, 21, 33, 45,

) %>% 
  mutate(selectYCol = glue::glue("V{Y}"))

#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#>   A         Y    V1    V2    V3 selectYCol
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <S3: glue>
#> 1 One       2    89    52    37 V2        
#> 2 Two       3    45    34    86 V3        
#> 3 alpha     1    33    36    43 V1        
#> 4 beta      1    21    33    45 V1
```

In selectYCol, we need the column value, instead of column name. The "V" is static and the number is based on Y column.

So, the selectYCol result should be 52, 86, 33, 21 which comes from V2, V3, V1, V1 columns respectively.

Note: There are two tibbles (attempts) trying to do the same thing with a different approach.

Comment: see this blog for a discussion on several methods and their efficiency: http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2018/09/using-a-column-as-a-column-index/  http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2018/09/timing-column-indexing-in-r/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the column name, as you do using `paste`, but you have to `get` the value, otherwise you'll just keep and use the name of the column. We can also use `rowwise` to let the process know which row we're interested in each time:

```
library(tidyverse)

df = tribble(
  ~A, ~Y, ~V1, ~V2, ~V3,
  "One", 2, 89, 52, 37,
  "Two", 3, 45, 34, 86,
  "alpha", 1, 33, 36, 43,
  "beta", 1, 21, 33, 45,
  ) 

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(selectYCol = get(paste0("V", Y))) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 4 x 6
#   A         Y    V1    V2    V3 selectYCol
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1 One       2    89    52    37         52
# 2 Two       3    45    34    86         86
# 3 alpha     1    33    36    43         33
# 4 beta      1    21    33    45         21
```

You can also use `map2` instead of `rowwise` and `pull` instead of `get`, like this:

```
df %>%
  nest(-A, -Y) %>%
  mutate(selectYCol = map2(Y, data, ~{.y %>% pull(paste0("V", .x))})) %>%
  unnest()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with the tidyverse :

```
library(tidyverse)
tribble(
  ~A, ~Y, ~V1, ~V2, ~V3,
  "One", 2, 89, 52, 37,
  "Two", 3, 45, 34, 86,
  "alpha", 1, 33, 36, 43,
  "beta", 1, 21, 33, 45,
) -> df
df %>% gather(k,v,-A,-Y) %>%
  filter(paste0("V", Y)==k) %>%
  select(A,v) %>%
  inner_join(df,.,by="A")
## A tibble: 4 x 6
#  A         Y    V1    V2    V3     v
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 One       2    89    52    37    52
#2 Two       3    45    34    86    86
#3 alpha     1    33    36    43    33
#4 beta      1    21    33    45    21
```